# C# Simulating Excel pivot feature with T-Sql Group by

Tags: c#, t-sql, ms-access, pivot

I've got the prototype of the system down in excel, and i'm now trying to migrate it into t-sql, for use with an Access Database, C#.

Anyways, I have a table like this:

[image: First table]

Desired output would look like this:

[image: Last Table]

So as far as I understand query syntax, `Group by` and `Sum` is key here. However, I don't know how to do a multiple condition `Group by`, and create the table parts. Not sure if I need a `Distinct`, since Group by is essentially the same thing.

So far, this is what I have

```
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select DISTINCT ([Locale]), SUM([Value]) AS 'Totals' FROM [" + Current_Table + "] GROUP BY [Locale]", connection);
```

This doesn't actually do what I want it to do, it collects the total values of Locale, but it ignores type. but it's a step in the right direction I think, I just don't know how to involve more conditions, since the compiler keeps spitting missing operator errors.

Am I correct in assuming this is a multiple query problem? Where, after I generate the first column, I need to write another query or the next one and append it to a temporary column etc? OR can this be done in one go? It was alot easier to do this in Excel.

Regarding the pivot, is my current process correct in that the columns are generated as new with `As` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the answer is pretty simple. What you're looking for is the pivot feature you might have heard of from Excel. This is present in Access as well as other `RDBMS`. This is what I settled with (Different example):

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Amount_USD) AS Sums SELECT DISTINCT Accounts AS Unadjusted FROM [" + Current_Table + "]  GROUP BY Accounts PIVOT Status
```

Kevin's suggestion is also another way to do this, but the values will end up being hard coded. This way, you will be using a native feature of `Access` (a plus, if that's what you're using) and you'll keep things simple.

You can place that line of code as a query for your `OleDb` commands.

I apologize in advance since I had to answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if ms-access will support this statement, but here is the query that can provide your result. As input I used the rows of your screenshot. As you can see when using PIVOT you need to know the columnnames in front. If not you will need to go with a dynamic query, I don't think ms-access will support this.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (VALUE INT, LOCALE VARCHAR(255), [TYPE] VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(7,'Argentina','Expense'),
(8,'Columbia','Revenue'),
(9,'Antarctica','Other'),
(99,'Argentina','Expense'),
(12,'Columbia','Revenue'),
(12,'Columbia','Expense'),
(50,'Argentina','Other')

SELECT pivr.TYPE, pivr.Antarctica, pivr.Argentina, pivr.Columbia, tot.Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS sort, t.Value, t.Locale, t.[Type]
        FROM @t AS t
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS sort, SUM(t.Value), t.Locale, 'Total'
        FROM @t AS t
        GROUP BY t.LOCALE
    ) AS s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(VALUE) FOR LOCALE IN (Argentina,Columbia,Antarctica)
    ) piv
) AS pivr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Type], SUM(Value) AS Total
    FROM @t 
    GROUP BY [Type]
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Total', Sum(VALUE) 
    FROM @t) AS tot
ON tot.[Type] = pivr.[Type]
```

Result

```
TYPE     Antarctica  Argentina  Columbia  Total
------------------------------------------------
Expense  NULL        106        12        118
Other    9           50         NULL      59
Revenue  NULL        NULL       20        20
Total    9           156        32        197
```

Comment: I've tried it, and it seems to work as expected. However, I recently learned about a feature of MS Access that trivialized this issue of mine, the code is as follows: `TRANSFORM SUM(Amount_USD) AS Sums SELECT DISTINCT Accounts AS Unadjusted FROM [" + Current_Table + "]  GROUP BY Accounts PIVOT Status` Though your answer did point me in the right direction!